# iPhone:- Link Identify From Label Text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

In my iPhone application, I want to show the link inside my label in different color (like a hyperlink).

When someone clicks on the link, it should open the link in Safari browser.

How can I do so?

Comment: where is display text in UITextview ot Webview..?

Comment: in uilabel not in uitextview ot webiview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hear is Two example sample code link is bellow hope its helps you:-

https://github.com/twotoasters/TTTAttributedLabel

http://furbo.org/stuff/FancyLabel_1.0.zip

**OR you can also do like this way**

Set userInteractionEnabled to YES of your label and add a gesture recognizer to it:

```
myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openUrl:)];
    gestureRec.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    gestureRec.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [myLabel addGestureRecognizer:gestureRec];
    [gestureRec release];

Then implement the action method:

    - (void)openUrl:(id)sender
    {
        UIGestureRecognizer *rec = (UIGestureRecognizer *)sender;

        id hitLabel = [self.view hitTest:[rec locationInView:self.view] withEvent:UIEventTypeTouches];

        if ([hitLabel isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:((UILabel *)hitLabel).text]];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

We use regex to check link

```
NSString *urlRegEx =@"((http|https)://)?((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx];
if ([urlTest evaluateWithObject:lbl.text])
{
       //set color of lbl
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can identify in a label to know a hyperlink.

make a custom button looking like a label (only with text and background as clearColor), to give the effect.